# Backgroundtask is activated by SocketActivityTrigger, but the socket in the trigger returns null

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp, bluetooth, background-task

I want to be able to send and receive data over a socket using bluetooth when my app is suspended. I register my BackgroundReader once a connection is established in the foreground app.

Code run once a connection is established:

```
    private void OnConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {           
        BackgroundTaskRegistration receiveTask = RegisterBackgroundTask("X.ReceiverTask", "ReceiverTask", new SocketActivityTrigger(), null);
        BackgroundTaskRegistration sendTask = RegisterBackgroundTask("X.Z", "SenderTask", new ApplicationTrigger(), null);

        var socket = args.Socket;
        socket.EnableTransferOwnership(receiveTask.TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.DoNotWake);
        socket.TransferOwnership("RfcommSocket");
    }
```

Method to register a Background task:

```
     private static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint, string name, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition)
            {
                foreach(var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
                {
                    if(cur.Value.Name == name)
                    {
                        //task is already registered
                        return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
                    }
                }

                var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
                builder.Name = name;
                if(taskEntryPoint != null && taskEntryPoint != String.Empty)
                {
                    builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
                }
                builder.SetTrigger(trigger);

                if(condition != null)
                {
                    builder.AddCondition(condition);
                }

                BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
                return task;
            }
```

When I try to send data the Receiver background task activates as expected. Only when I try to read the stream socket from its properties, it returns null and throws an Exception when I try to access it:

```
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        taskDeferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled;
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as SocketActivityTriggerDetails;
        var socketInformation = details.SocketInformation;
        switch (details.Reason)
        {
            ...
            case SocketActivityTriggerReason.SocketActivity:
                Debug.WriteLine(socketInformation.SocketKind.ToString());
                var socket = socketInformation.StreamSocket; //This returns null
                DataReader reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
                reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
                await reader.LoadAsync(250);
                var dataString = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                Debug.WriteLine(dataString);
                socket.TransferOwnership(socketInformation.Id); /* Important! */
                break;
            ...
        }
        taskDeferral.Complete();
    }
```

The backgroundTaskHost.exe exits and, supposedly, takes the socket with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We could not use above code to create the complete sample that use to reproduce above issue, could you share a mini sample for testing?

Comment: I can give you access to my git repository. Would you be willing for me to add you as a collaborator?

Comment: If your project is no-public, please try to create a mini sample.

Comment: Please find a working sample of the Bluetooth Server here:
https://github.com/cmorschel/CommsHub

Comment: I check your project, but it  missed `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, could you add them?

Comment: The AssemblyInfo files have been added

Comment: Great, I will check you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Backgroundtask is activated by SocketActivityTrigger, but the socket in the trigger returns null

I checked your code, The problem is you used [`SocketActivityTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.socketactivitytrigger) in Bluetooth RF communication. In UWP we often use [`RfcommConnectionTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.rfcommconnectiontrigger) to detect Bluetooth message notification. The `RfcommConnectionTrigger` has more features that support Bluetooth RF communication. And I have test with official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat) and it could get the socket instance correctly and could load the message with reader.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented the official code sample and it works.